# How to keep object property "Required" conditionally, depending on object's use?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rest

I have one object which is being used everywhere. Now I want to make that object's properties required conditionally, depending on where object is being used.

Here is the example:

Here is the object which is going to be used everywhere,

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have one more class where above object is being used as property,

```
public class Registration
{
    public Contact ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public List<ChildContact> ChildContact { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is a "ChildContact" class, where "Contact" class is also used as property,

```
public class ChildContact
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public int NoOfStudents { get; set; }
}
```

So when "Contact" class is used in "Registration", FristName and LastName properties should be required but when it is used in "ChildContact", those properties should be optional.

Please help me get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're the developer of `Contact` and others use your library for their `Registration` and `ChildContact` there is no way to control the usage. Best case scenario you can create separate interfaces/classes for enforced/unenforced `Contact`.

If you control the full source code and just want to double check yourself, provide the setter that will check if those fields were assigned.

```
public class Registration
{
    private Contact _contactDetails;
    public Contact ContactDetails
    {
        get => _contactDetails;
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new NullReferenceException("...");
            if (value.FirstName == null || value.FirstName == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Provide first name.");
            if (value.LastName == null || value.LastName == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Provide last name.");
            _contactDetails = value;
        }
    }
    public List<ChildContact> ChildContact { get; set; }
}
```